# Nvidia Geforce 820M driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04, games

I have ubuntu 16.04, want to play games, 
But nvidia driver is not installed, Should I install the driver for better performance or Intel Graphics will cope up with it?

In additional drivers nvidia is not showing up! But when I run lspci the graphic card is there!

If I have to install the driver, which version is stable?

Comment: That depends on what games you want to play. In general, dedicated GPUs are be much more powerful than the integrated graphics processor.